# My program crashes on the Windows machine yet it works fine on the Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, stack-overflow

I tried to program Ackermann function on my notebook (Win10), however the program crashed at higher values instead of continuing to calculate for a few minutes or hours.

My friend tried the same code on his machine (SUSE) and it worked just fine, then we tried it on the school server (CentOS) and it crashed yet again.

EDIT: It worked on server too, it just needed a second try. It also worked on the other server we had tried... All of it is on Linux.

We suspect the stack overflow is behind it but it's weird, because values aren't THAT HIGH yet. How am I able to preform recursive functions on this system then?

Thanks for all the answers. I'm just curious why it happens and how to make it work on my machine.

I tried to use both C and C++ to no change.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ackermann (int m, int n);

int main () {

  int m = 4;
  int n = 1;

  return ackermann(m,n);
}

int ackermann (int m, int n)
{
  if      (m == 0)          return n=n+1;
  else if (m > 0 && n == 0) return ackermann(m-1,1);
  else if (m > 0 && n > 0)  return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n - 1));
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188055/discussion-on-question-by-scorpio11550-my-program-crashes-on-the-windows-machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio the default stack size is 1 MB, so with a recursion depth of 65535, and, I believe, a minimum stack frame for caller/function on x64 of this type is 72 bytes, so you will run out of available stack frame space for your program ( I compute almost 4.5Mb of stack needed for this scenario). This also produced the stack buffer overflow error, and has nothing to do with stack smashing other than you went beyond the maximum stack size available to your program when compiled.

Most compilers including Visual Studio let you specify the stack size.

More details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=vs-2017

[ Edited to reflect 65,535 frames, and not 1.4 billion ]

Comment: @TedLyngmo I amended my comment.  The issue still appears to exist, unless using a compiler other than MSVC with a bigger default program stack limit on windows.

Comment: Yes, it's surely exceeding the stack limit in some environments. 65536(!) is pretty deep.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it's stack smashing, or more accurately a [stack buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow), which is the error message you got. The function has a very large depth, and will keep on pushing variables on the stack. If you push enough variables onto the stack, it'll smash. The computer doesn't have infinite memory for the stack and from the sounds of it, not a crazy amount either.

Given big enough input, it should stack any smash if not optimized well (and might still anyways). Without knowing more about your compiler, there can't be a comprehensive option on how to disable it, but if you're using Microsoft Visual Studio's compiler suite, you can disable the protection [if I understand this doc correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check?view=vs-2017).

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and then click Properties
2. In the Property Pages dialog box, click the C/C++ folder.
3. Click the Code Generation property page.
4. Modify the Buffer Security Check property.

As a warning, **this is not safe** and bad things can happen, so use this at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not going to risk it though. I use simpler IDEs like Code::Blocks and Dev C++ because Visual Studio is something "out of my league". I just don't believe in myself enough to start using it. 

Now I understand the problem little bit more, sadly, as I'm new here, my upvote doesn't show.

I just don't understand why I have "so small stack" compared to Linux terminal :-/